# setup SameSite=none value in Nginx webserver

Tags: nginx, headers, cookie

I need to setup `SameSite=none` value in Nginx webserver

In case of using Nginx as main webserver and non reverse proxy will the below configuration work?

**Inside server block**

```
location {

proxy_cookie_path ~(.*) "$1; SameSite=none; secure; httponly";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can only add `SameSite` support. For change it, you have to install Nginx 1.19.3 and set as below:

```
proxy_cookie_flags one samesite=none;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_flags